# Powershell getting full path information

Tags: powershell

I have a directory called Videos. Inside this directory, are a bunch of sub directories of various cameras. I have a script that will check each of the various cameras, and delete recordings older than a certain date.

I am having a bit of trouble getting the full directory information for the cameras. I am using the following to get it:

```
#Get all of the paths for each camera
$paths = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Videos\" | Select-Object FullName
```

And then I loop through each path in $paths and delete whatever I need to:

```
foreach ($pa in $paths) {
    # Delete files older than the $limit.
    $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $pa -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } 
    $file | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
    $file | Select -Expand FullName | Out-File $logFile -append
}
```

When I run the script, I am getting errors such as:

```
@{FullName=C:\Videos\PC1-CAM1}
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{FullName=C' does not exist.
At C:\scripts\BodyCamDelete.ps1:34 char:13
+     $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $pa -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsCont ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{FullName=C:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Is there a way to strip that @{FullName= off of the Path? I think that may be what the issue is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case `$pa` is an object with a FullName property. The way you would access that would be this.

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $pa.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }
```

However it would just be simpler to change only this line and leave

```
$paths = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Videos\" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

`-ExpandProperty` will just return the string instead of the object that `Select-Object` was returning.

Answer (score 3):

You are nearly there. What you want is the -ExpandProperty argument for Select-Object. This will return the value of that property, instead of a FileInfo object with one property, that property being FullName. This should resolve it for you:

```
$paths = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Videos\" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

**Edit:** Looks like Matt beat me to it by a minute.